# Re-throw exception in task (TPL) loses stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I've code that rethrows an exception.

When I later read the exception from task.Exception, its stacktrace points to the location where I re-threw the exception (line n and not line m, as I expected).

Why is this so? bug in TPL or more likely something I have overlooked.

As I workaround I can wrap the exception as the inner-exception in a new exception.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskMethod).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.InnerException));
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void TaskMethod()
    {
        try
        {
line m:     throw new Exception("Todo");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
line n:     throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `throw` replacing the line number issue is reasonably well known. There's a [blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx) discussing a possible workaround, but I've not used it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the way TPL stores exceptions until the task finished executing, the original stack trace is lost. Running your sample code in LINQPad shows that the exception was thrown at `at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()`, which is obviously not correct.

As a crude workaround, you *could* store the original stack trace (it being a simple string) on the `Data` property of the original exception, and you'll be able to access it then:

```
private static void TaskMethod()
{
    try
    {           
        throw new Exception("Todo");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data["OriginalStackTrace"] = ex.StackTrace;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have the original stack trace stored in the `OriginalStackTrace` value of the `Data` dictionary:

[image]

It's not really what you want, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Now I know that's just the way it is. I think I'll just wrap the exception like throw new Exception("See inner exception", e);